# RHadoop - Rstudio - Install arulesViz library

Tags: arules, rhadoop, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I'm trying to install the arulesViz library using RStudion in Cloudera Machine. For that I'm executing:

```
install.packages("arulesViz", type = "source")
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/cloudera/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘curl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/cloudera/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘plotly’
* removing ‘/home/cloudera/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/plotly’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘plotly’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘plotly’ is not available for package ‘arulesViz’
* removing ‘/home/cloudera/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/arulesViz’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘arulesViz’ had non-zero exit status
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package curl has the following requirements (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html):

**SystemRequirements:** libcurl: libcurl-devel (rpm) or libcurl4-openssl-dev (deb).

Install the library and it will probably work.